# Can't you sleep also?

Tags: questions

> Can't you sleep also?

Is it well said? I want to ask if you can't sleep, like me.

Comment: Can't you sleep either?

Comment: I don't think it was pointed out in the linked thread that '... that you too/also can't V' _is_ quite common. '... there's no reason that you too can't enjoy as many aspects of the horse world as you'd like to' (internet). But 'either' is usually required, as in OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use the word "also" when you are in positive agreement. In this case the sentence is a negative one and you would use either instead.

```
Can't you sleep either?
```

Also:

```
I can sleep, can you also sleep?
Yes, I can also sleep.
```

Either:

```
I'm not sleeping well, can't you sleep either?
No, I can't sleep either.
```

[This link](http://www.ecenglish.com/learnenglish/lessons/also-too-either) has a pretty good explanation about the difference between ***Also***, ***Too***, and ***Either***.